# Real Analysis: Showing uniform convergence on $[, \infty)$ and $[0,\infty)$ for sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{1+nx}$ for $ x \ge 0$.

I successfully proved that if $t > 0$, then convergence is uniform on $[t,\infty)$.

I am now asked to prove that convergence is **not** uniform on $[0,\infty)$.

---

$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ , $x = 0$

The problem is I can't believe I can use that in writing $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ since $x=0$ is just one case. Any advice? Thank you greatly in advance!

Comment: **Hint:** The [Uniform Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem) says that the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x\ne 0$, then  $$ \lim _{n\to \infty } f_n(x) =\lim _{n\to \infty }  \frac{nx}{1+nx}=1$$

On the other hand if $x=0$ we have  $$ \lim _{n\to \infty } f_n(x) =\lim _{n\to \infty } 0 =0$$

Let $\epsilon =1/2$, then for a given $\delta >0 $ you can find two points, $x=\delta /2$ and $y=0$ such that $$ |x-y|< \delta $$ and $$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|>1/2$$ for large enough n.

Thus the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I hope this isn't a silly question but is it sufficient to say that it cannot be uniform since $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 1$ for $x \ne 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$?

Comment: That is exactly the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that it were, then $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)$, we have for some $N$ that
\begin{align*}
\left|\chi_{(0,\infty)}(x)-\dfrac{nx}{1+nx}\right|<\dfrac{1}{2},~~~~n\geq N,~~~~x\in[0,\infty).
\end{align*}
Fix the $n=N$, then for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ we have
\begin{align*}
\left|1-\dfrac{Nx}{1+Nx}\right|<\dfrac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
taking $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$, we have $1<1/2$, which is absurb.

Answer (score 1):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that there exists a function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$
uniformly on $[0,\infty)$. In particular, $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwisely.
By direct calculation of pointwise limit, we have 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{ if }x=0\\
1, & \mbox{ if }x\in(0,\infty)
\end{cases}.
$$
Recall that uniform limit of continuous functions is also continuous,
so $f$ is continuous, which is a contradiction.

Alternatively, we can prove it directly without using the fact that
``uniform limit of continuous functions is also continuous''. Since
$f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly, for $\varepsilon=0.01$, there exists
$N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever
$x\in[0,\infty)$ and $n\geq N$. In particular, $|f_{N}(\frac{1}{N})-f(\frac{1}{N})|<\varepsilon$.
Note that $f_{N}(\frac{1}{N})=\frac{1}{2}$ while $f(\frac{1}{N})=0$.
Therefore $|\frac{1}{2}-0|<0.01$ which is a contradiction.